# What does "productService" mean in Kendo UI Grid/Inline editing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, kendo-grid

I'm trying to create a DataGrid using Kendo UI, when I read at code line:

```
private ProductService productService;

    public GridController()
    {
        productService = new ProductService(new SampleEntities());
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        productService.Dispose();

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

I don't know what `productService` is? Can anyone explain it to me where that comes from and how does it work in that `Controller`? FYI that [link](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/index.html). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get confused with this...its just a sample code.

for this example grid CustomerViewModel is bound to the grid..

***********************Grid*******************

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CustomerViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName).Width(140);
            columns.Bound(c => c.ContactTitle).Width(190);
            columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyName);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Country).Width(110);
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Grid"))
        )
    )
```

*******************Controller Functions***********

```
public ActionResult Customers_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(GetCustomers().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        private static IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> GetCustomers()
        {
            var northwind = new SampleEntities();
            return northwind.Customers.Select(customer => new CustomerViewModel
            {
                CustomerID = customer.CustomerID,
                CompanyName = customer.CompanyName,
                ContactName = customer.ContactName,
                ContactTitle = customer.ContactTitle,
                Address = customer.Address,
                City = customer.City,
                Region = customer.Region,
                PostalCode = customer.PostalCode,
                Country = customer.Country,
                Phone = customer.Phone,
                Fax = customer.Fax,
                Bool = customer.Bool
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for providing example.  I had the same question as Mr. Pham.  Also, this site provides another example:   http://telerikhelper.net/2014/01/06/kendo-ui-grid-wrapper-for-asp-net-mvcgetting-started/

Comment: Make sure you include:  using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions; for [DataSourceRequest]